# PyMongo retrieve database value

Tags: pymongo

I have a multi-level mongo database collection. I am trying to extract data from it using PyMongo but I keep getting the error:

TypeError: string indices must be integers

I have tried this many different ways but keep getting the same result. I must be missing something very simple but can't seem to identify it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import pymongo
import json
server = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost')
db = server['testData']
inventory = db['testCollection']

db.inventory.insert_many([
    {
     "data_set1": [
         {
             "paramGroup1" : [
                 {
                     "dataItem1" : 14, "dataItem2" : 1233, "dataItem3" : 1234
                     }]
             },
         {
             "paramGroup2" : [
                 {
                     "dataItem1" : 15, "dataItem2" : 1234, "dataItem3" : 1235
                     }]
             }
         ]
     },
    {
     "data_set2": [
         {
             "paramGroup1" : [
                 {
                     "dataItem1" : 16, "dataItem2" : 1254, "dataItem3" : 1111
                     }]
             },
         {
             "paramGroup2" : [
                 {
                     "dataItem1" : 51, "dataItem2" : 9999, "dataItem3" : 2222
                     }]
             }
        ]
     },
   ])

cursor = db.inventory.find(
    {'data_set1': {"$exists": 1}})

string_output = ''
for doc in cursor:
    string_output = string_output + str(doc)
    #print(str(doc))

jDumpsData = json.dumps(string_output)
print("jDumpsData = " + jDumpsData)
jLoadsData = json.loads(jDumpsData)
print("jLoadsData = " + jLoadsData)
testDataItem = jLoadsData['data_set1']['paramGroup2']['dataItem3']
```

In this instance, I'm expecting to get the value 1234 for data_set1->paramGroup2->dataItem3. Really I just want to assign the value of dataItem3 to a variable and just it in other calculations.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the value 1234 for data_set1->paramGroup2->dataItem3 you can access it with the the code below. you don't need to dump and load json.
your json data contains multiple json and list, in this situation debugging will help you find your simple mistake easily.

```
cursor = db.inventory.find(
    {'data_set1': {"$exists": 1}})

data = list(cursor)
print(data[0]["data_set1"][1]["paramGroup2"][0]["dataItem3"])
```

Comment: This is very helpful! Thank you. I have updated the code to reference using the index and it worked perfectly. Follow-on question: what if I do not know the index. For instance I want to return result of data_set1->paramGroup2->dataItem3, but I don't know the index of paramGroup2 (just this key name). Will I have to iterate through each index searching or is there an easier way? Thanks again!

Comment: Perhaps I need to insert the database into a different format somehow. I have tried several permutations to no avail so far.